# Pick database for ads/analytics service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cassandra, analytics, nosql

Now I have a project with ads exchange service (something like google double click) and I have to pick a high-scalable database. I'm thinking about mongodb or cassandra.

Cassandra:

- fit with our write-intensive system. (+)
- looks hard to do aggregate(very important for analytics) (is there a good way? Just read slide about Twitter rainbird, seem good) (?)
- I dont prefer java much. (-)

MongoDB:

- Seem easier to do analytics. (have build-in aggregate functions) (+)
- more RAM-consuming? (because of document-oriented vs key-value Cassandra) (?)
- write perfomance compare to Cassandra? (?)
- javascript shell and natural fit with node.js(one important part in our project) (+)
- http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FD3xe6Jt - This article make me cautious. (-)

Can you guys help me to pick the one or answer some of my questions above

Thanks.

Comment: Just to help stop the meme: that 'article' on pastebin is a hoax, unless you believe someone hacked the HN account of the original poster. See http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3202081 I also blogged about it: http://waistcode.net/blog/dont-not-use-mongodb

Comment: You should also look at HBase for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about Cassandra, but MongoDB has some advantages for using it for analytics: high concurrency, sharding, storing everything about an event in a single document, features like [upsert](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) and [$inc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating).

For more detailed explanations check the following resources:

[MongoDB Analytics - videos](http://www.10gen.com/presentations#application__analytics) 
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/171353301/using-mongodb-for-real-time-analytics 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases 
http://www.slideshare.net/jrosoff/scalable-event-analytics-with-mongodb-ruby-on-rails 
http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/3508305955/fast-asynchronous-analytics-with-mongodb 
http://blog.opengovernment.org/2011/02/24/fast-asynchronous-analytics-with-mongodb/ 
http://blog.10gen.com/post/4416876632/london-startup-ubervu-on-storing-5tb-of-data-in-mongodb

Comment: Thanks for useful articles. Also I'm curious about write performance and RAM/CPU usage between two.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on your domain, most cases one would probably choose Mongo.
For example http://square.github.com/cube/ is built on Mongo.

> Cube is an open-source system for visualizing time series data, built on MongoDB, Node and D3. If you send Cube timestamped events (with optional structured data), you can easily build realtime visualizations of aggregate metrics for internal dashboards. For example, you might use Cube to monitor traffic to your website, counting the number of requests in 5-minute intervals:

Most use cases of Cassandra draw from the need oh **high availability** that's the main feature of it afaik. Your needs seem to be centered around having a cheap way to shove queryable data in a scale-out DB, and mongo almost matches RDBMS in regards to querying. Mongo is also probably easier to deal with.

Comment: Hmm, availability isn't the main problem of me. If the performance of mongodb is good enough (compare to Cassandra), it's clearly win for Mongo? Also, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think cassandra is a good fit for this problem.

You don't need to know much java to get it running (other than install java), as long as there is a client library in your chosen language.

Cassandra 0.8+ now has [atomic counter support](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters) - perfect for impressions/click tracking.

You could also run [hadoop on top of cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport), giving you a proven platform for writing map reduce jobs to do analytics/aggregations and store the results back to Cassandra too.

Check out this slideshow about cassandra and hadoop: http://www.slideshare.net/jeromatron/cassandrahadoop-4399672

I hope that helps.